# Flutter base64 image string issue

Tags: flutter, dart

I am taking screenshot of my widget and converting into base64 string and send to whatsapp as an image. But issue is when I am sending its not showing image but if i use hardcoded plugin provided string its working fine.

This is my code

```
   screenshotController
        .capture(delay: Duration(milliseconds: 10))
        .then((Uint8List image) async {
      _imageFile = image;
      print(base64Encode(_imageFile));

      FlutterShareMe()
          .shareToWhatsApp(base64Image: base64Encode(_imageFile));

    }).catchError((onError) {
      print(onError);
    });
```

Its not showing image on whats app but if i use hardcoded string as provided by plugin like this

```
String base64Image =
  "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4QAqRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAABADEBAgAHAAAAGgAAAAAAAABHb29nbGUAAP/bAIQAAwICCAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICggICAgJCQkICA0NCggNCAgJCAEDBAQGB
```

If i try to use this string its too long but to show this  just pick chunk of string then its working fine i am doing anything wrong in encoded base64 ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `data:image/jpeg;base64` image in start in string

Like this

```
FlutterShareMe().shareToWhatsApp(base64Image: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64Encode(_imageFile)}');
```